# i am facing an error in running a server , i try to open the port on 3000 but it is not working and also after change port no. still it is the same

Tags: express, npm, server

node:events:491
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 3005;
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1767:8)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
code: 'EACCES',
errno: -4092,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '3005;',
port: -1
}

after changing the port also this error is not resolved

Comment: Are you running this twice in a row?  You can get this error if you try to serve on a port where there is already a server.

Comment: yes but i also change the ports to 3005 and 8000 also

Comment: Try again with any firewall software disabled.

Comment: One error I sometimes see is for people to call `listen` in a loop.  They run `listen`, then wait for an incoming, then handle it, then loop around and call `listen` again.  That causes this problem.  `listen` should be called exactly once.